# Why is "when" used in this function?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, guard

There is this index function in "Erlang Programming":

```
index(0, [X|_]) -> X;
index(N, [_|Xs]) when N>0 -> index(N-1, Xs)
```

Isn't the guard "when N>0" superfluous because of the pattern matching? Calling index(0, List) will never end up in the second clause so N will always be > 0. Or am I totally wrong here?

Comment: don't know Erlang (only OCaml) so I'll leave it as a comment: Which pattern would match N==-1 My guess would be the second (if it wasn't for the guard)

Comment: Rune FS, That was my first thought too, but index(-1,[1,2,3]) results in "** exception error: no function clause matching test:index(-1,[1,2,3])"

Comment: but if you remove the guard doesn't that match then?

Comment: @Rune FS, Without the guard erl gives me "** exception error: no function clause matching test:index(-4,[])". But now it is obvious :) The error message is better with the guard.

Comment: not only that, but it errors on the *first* call instead of going 3-deep into recursion. Now, `index` is a very simple function, so you hardly notice, but imagine if it wasn't. Best to find errors sooner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function works correctly for N>=0. Without a guard, for N<0 it would traverse the whole list:

index(-2,[1,2,3]) -> index(-3,[2,3]) -> ... -> index(-5,[]) -> error.

That isn't a large problem, only you might get a confusing exception. In languages with infinite lists (Haskell, Ocaml), forgetting about that guard might lead to infinite loop: index(-1, [0,0,0..]).

Answer (score 6):

The when clause guards against negative indices (edit: see comments to original question ;).

Answer (score 5):

It also gives clearer code as you explicitly say when this clause is valid, not just by default. Yes, I know that in some (many) cases this is not possible to do properly as the test may become very complex or that you want some form of default case. But not here.